# Find the domain name and replace it - Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have moved a website to another subdomain and some of the hard coded link are causing problem.

Original website

```
<pre>
www.example.com
</pre>
```

New Website

```
<pre>
subdomain.example.com
</pre>
```

Some of the php code in the files reside in the www directory has www.example.com in them. How can find the "www.example.com" in the *.php pages and replace them with "subdomain.example.com". There are in recursive directories as well so I would like to change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily from the command line via

```
find /path/to/files -name '*.php' | xargs sed -i -e s/www.example.com/subdomain.example.com/g
```

You can adjust the file set by sending extra parameters to `find` and you can do a more sophisticated replacement by adjusting the expression given to `sed` (for example, to ensure the matched pattern is a whole word).

Answer (score 0):

This Python script *should* do the trick http://pastebin.com/fn8kDmHz